# Chart not showing data when selecting data with vba

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm using VBA to update my chart. With VBA I select the data that should be shown in the chart. My code does select the data, but somehow my chart doesn't show anything. When I click on my chart end select "Select data" it does show selected data, bu somehow my chart is still empty. Because my chart is empty, the rest of my code doesn't work

My chart is a combo chart with both dataranges as bars, absolute on the primary axis and relative on the secondary axis.

```
    Dim DataSite As Range
    Dim DataAbsolute As Range
    Dim DataRelative As Range

    Set DataSite = Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(7, 1).End(xlDown))
    Set DataAbsolute = Range(Cells(7, 4), Cells(7, 4).End(xlDown))
    Set DataRelative = Range(Cells(7, 5), Cells(7, 5).End(xlDown))

    GraphsFrames.Select
    For Each serie In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
        serie.Select
        serie.Delete
    Next serie

    With cht.Chart
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = DataSite
            .Values = DataAbsolute
            .Name = "Absolute"
            .AxisGroup = 1
        End With

        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Values = DataRelative
            .Name = "Relative"
            .AxisGroup = 2
        End With
        .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 50
        .ChartGroups(2).GapWidth = 300
        .Refresh
    End With
```

What can I do to make sure my chart shows the data selected?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what GraphFrames is, so I ignored it. I made only minor adjustments to your code, below, and it worked just fine. I assume the data is on the active sheet, and so is the chart object you're adding data to.

```
Sub DoChartData()
    Dim DataSite As Range
    Dim DataAbsolute As Range
    Dim DataRelative As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set DataSite = .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(7, 1).End(xlDown))
        Set DataAbsolute = .Range(.Cells(7, 4), .Cells(7, 4).End(xlDown))
        Set DataRelative = .Range(.Cells(7, 5), .Cells(7, 5).End(xlDown))
    End With

    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)

    Dim serie As Series
    For Each serie In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
        serie.Delete
    Next serie

    With cht.Chart
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = DataSite
            .Values = DataAbsolute
            .Name = "Absolute"
            .AxisGroup = 1
        End With

        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Values = DataRelative
            .Name = "Relative"
            .AxisGroup = 2
        End With
        .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 50
        .ChartGroups(2).GapWidth = 300
    End With
End Sub
```